# Name is not defined while trying to get request.user to use in a form

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I know this question was asked many times but I keep getting the same error with the solutions posted in stackoverflow. I am probably making a simple mistake but as a beginner, I don't realy see where is my mistake.

Here is my **forms.py**:

```
from django import forms
from .models import *

class AddMark(forms.Form):

    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = user
        super(AddMark, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)      
    
    teacher = Teacher.objects.filter(user = self.user)[:1]
    modules = Module.objects.filter(enseignants__in = (teacher))

    desc = forms.CharField(label='Description')
    coef = forms.FloatField(label='Coefficient')
    max_mark = forms.FloatField(label='Max Mark')
    module = forms.ChoiceField(label='Module',choices=modules)
```

and it seems like error comes from

```
    teacher = Teacher.objects.filter(user = self.user)[:1]
```

[image]

Comment: Well, I abandoned Django forms and wrote my own form in html and handled the POST request in a view. :/ I would still hear if someone got a solution for future projects

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
    user = user
    super(AddMark, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you reference self.user outside of a method that has that information.

If you want to perform these operations when the form is submitted you should probably put them inside the is_valid() method.

```
class AddMark(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = user
        super(AddMark, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)      

    def is_valid(self):
        teacher = Teacher.objects.filter(user = self.user)[:1]
        modules = Module.objects.filter(enseignants__in = (teacher))
```

When in doubt i always find it helpful to go see django's source code on github, it can really dispel a lot of the mystery surrounding its classes!
https://github.com/django/django/blob/f5e5aac59ebbcea46b98d37834915de0f43d7cc8/django/forms/forms.py#L22